# java Querydsl wrong result with or()

Tags: java, querydsl

I'm new to querydsl and probably I miss the concept somehow.
What I want to do is fetch all person objects, who's name starts with "He", or who's birthday has passed or who's adresses' street starts with "ge".

When I use the snippet here, I only get the person objects who match the third condition (person.adresse.strasse). The first zwo conditions are completely ignored.
If I comment out the third condition, I get the results where the two first conditions (person.name machtes or person.birthday.before) matches.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to do a join instead?

```
List<Person> persons = query.select( person )
            .from( person )
            .where(
                    person.name.startsWith( "He" )
                    .or( person.birthday.before( new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() ) )
                            .or( person.adresse.strasse.startsWithIgnoreCase( "ge" ) ) )
            )
            .fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong number of parenthesis.

Unintentionally, you have nested the third `or` inside the second one, that's why when you comment the third `or` you get correct results.

Try this:

```
List<Person> persons = query.select( person )
            .from( person )
            .where(
                    person.name.startsWith("He")
                    .or(person.birthday.before(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                    .or(person.adresse.strasse.startsWithIgnoreCase("ge")) 
            )
            .fetch();
```

It should work.

Comment: Unfortunatly this does'nt solve the issue. I can reduce the snippt and still have the same problem:  List<Person> persons = query.select( person )
                .from( person )
                .where(
                        person.name.startsWith( "He" )
                        .or( person.adresse.strasse.startsWithIgnoreCase( "ge" ) )
                )
                .fetch();

Comment: Strange, I just tested it and it works. Might help if you include in your question entity code, db schema and a sample of db data. Are you really using query's dsl generated qEntities?

Comment: When I remove one of the two conditions, I get the expected result. But as soon as I add the condition for person.adresse.street, I get only the persons that match that condition. The persons which meet the first condition (person.name) are ignored.
If I'd replace the second condition with something like person.birthday instead of person.adresse.street, everything works fine. It seems it's a problem that person.name and person.adresse.street reference different objects ?!

Comment: Tried to rewrite the example to put it here. But now I can't reproduce it anymore. So, issue solved...